# How to get StatusCode for Initiator 'document' (HttpResponse)

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm working on my .NET console application which reads a bunch of URLs and then it makes HTTP request to them. Once the request has been made, it takes its status code and saves it to other property.

Here's my current code:

```
int _idCntr = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Executing tests, please hold!");
            
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", CredentialsBase64);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
                
                foreach (var test in Tests) {
                    try {
                        Console.WriteLine($"-> Checking:\n   {test.Name}: {test.URL}");
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(test.URL);
                        test.RunBy = $"{Environment.UserName} ({Environment.MachineName})";

                        // Debugging: Print response headers
                        foreach (var header in response.Headers) {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}");
                        }

                        string _initiator = response.Headers.TryGetValues("Initiator", out var _initiatorValues) ? _initiatorValues.FirstOrDefault() : null;

                        if (_initiator?.Equals("document", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true) {
                            int _code = (int)response.StatusCode;
                            test.ReturnCode = _code;

                            if (_code >= 100 && _code <= 299) {
                                test.Result = "Pass";
                            } else if (_code >= 300 && _code <= 399) {
                                test.Result = "Redirect";
                            } else if (_code >= 400 && _code <= 499) {
                                test.Result = "Possible fail - client";
                            } else if (_code >= 500 && _code <= 599) {
                                test.Result = "Fail";
                            } else {
                                test.Result = "Unknown";
                            }
                        }
                        
                        test.Id = _idCntr;
                        _idCntr++;
                    } catch (TaskCanceledException) {
                        test.Result = "Timeout";
                        Console.WriteLine($"Timeout for '{test.Name}' ({test.URL})!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is that it gets only the last code. I don't need the last code, I need whatever code but for **initiator 'document'**. How can achieve this?

I don't want to use Selenium or anything similar as I need to keep this application *as light as possible*, and every new nuget I add makes it more complex.

I tried handling the codes differently, but the best way would be if I only got the code for 'document'; that way the final property value would be most precise.

Comment: What do you mean you only get the last code? Do you mean that all the tests have the status code of the last one that ran?

Comment: @baynezy, I might've said something wrong... What I mean is that when I try to get the status code for a 'Test' object, it'd set its 'Result' property to the last code it got for that specific URL. For example, when I have a random URL to visit, I'd get a bunch of codes; among them is the code '200' for Initiator 'document' (which is what I want/need), but the last code I get (403, for example), is what will be set to 'Result' property. In this case, it sets 403 as 'Result' as it's the last code I received upon visiting specific URL.

Comment: I am still unclear. How are you getting a bunch of codes when visiting a URL? A status code is a singular thing. I call a URL I get a status code. Never many.

Comment: @baynezy, try inspecting the page you're on and go to 'Network' section (in case of using Firefox). When inspecting this very page I'd get about 10 codes, all of which are 200. Out of those 10 codes, the one I need to get is the one with 'document' as an Initiator. Because of receiving multiple codes, I'd get the wrong code sometimes and that cannot happen (when application gets code 403 - that should be pass as the account the 'test' ran from doesn't have the access, but the site is up and running).